# What's going on with the meta site in terms of badges/points?

Tags: discussion

This is probably meta-meta but we don't have a site for that (or is there some sort of meta area51 site for this?).

I noticed my points from Cooking carry over to the meta site, but my badges don't. Is this the intended behavior? It seems like it should either all carry over or none of it should.

Further I just noticed that getting upvoted on an answer here didn't seem to affect my points at all (although it did grant me a "Teacher" badge, so now I'm all sorts of confused as to how the system works here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the [FAQ](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/faq).

> Reputation here is entirely derived
>   from the parent website, and
>   synchronized hourly. Your reputation
>   here is the same as your reputation on
>   the parent website. Votes here do not
>   affect your reputation on the parent
>   site. However, you can earn badges
>   here on the meta site.

Comment: Thanks, guess I should learn to RTFM. I still think it's a bit confusing though, especially since my summary pages shows the rep I've earned. It just doesn't seem fully worked out.

Comment: You're not the only one.  The question has been asked on the other betas as well.

Comment: I really wish all metas worked this way..